# Ubuntu 12.10, Intel 945GM and Google Earth

Tags: 12.10, google-earth

I have an Acer Aspire 4710-2057 with 1 Gb Ram and Intel 945GM Graphics Board.

When I runed Google Earth for the first time it complained that my board has insufficient video memory, but it runs only doesn't show the globe (coutry borders are there). I have intel drivers installed (it was installed by default on Ubuntu installation).
Unity is running in 3d mode.

Anyone has seen something like this ?

-Nelson

Answer (score 0):

Look here
https//bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1030190

or search here

This guide offers an alternative method of loading i915 driver

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.